# htlatex define proper bounding box dvi

Tags: htlatex, dvips, ghostscript

Is there a way to define the proper bounding box size inside latex files so that htlatex and then dvips make the right size graphics?

Right now it is cutting off the graphics too short.

I am using this convert line inside my tex4ht.env file

```
 Gdvips  -q -Ppdf -K -f -X 8.333333333 -Y 8.333333333 -x 0.9 -y 0.9 %%1 -pp %%2 > zz%%4.ps
% Ggs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=%%3 -r110x110 -dEPSCrop -dBackgroundColor=16#ffffff -dTextAlphaBits=2 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=2 -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE zz%%4.ps -c quit
```

to account for 600/72  resolution / DPI

but it's not altering output.

Dropbox tarball - https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwg161gc7927zrs/example-png.tar.gz?dl=0

I use the command htlatex hand-2_ItsATrap.tex  pngconfig.cfg ./tex4ht.env

and I ignore the \makeratletter errors - they don't affect output.

When you run it you will find too tight bounding boxes.

Thanks

Comment: could you post complete example what you are doing? if I understand correctly, you include images in eps format and they are cut off?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwg161gc7927zrs/example-png.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: That tarball holds my example folder

Comment: it seems there is some problem with postscript generated by `poker` package, both dvipng and dvisvgm don't like it